# How to not let the potential scrollbar affect the padding?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've developed a complete representation of the problem below:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 300px;
}

.button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #698fc3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to have the blue button at the bottom right always stick to the bottom right, regardless of scroll position.

The problem is that this container doesn't always have a scrollbar. When that happens, it is no longer aligned. Ideally, I'd like to set the `right` of the `button` to `8px`, but then it is positioned on top of the scrollbar.

Is there any way to align it to the bottom right of the div regardless of the scroll position and whether or not there is a scrollbar? It seems like currently I'd have to use Javascript to conditionally set the `right` property to `8px` when a scrollbar isn't present.

Answer (score 0):

Make the button inside the outer element and use `position:sticky` like below:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.outer {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 300px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #698fc3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  
  flex-shrink: 0;
  /* margin-top same as width, auto for the left and the offset you want for the right and bottom*/
  margin: -32px 8px 8px auto; 
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br
      />
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />a<br />
    </div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The scrollbar still overlaps the circle. It's the right position that the op is looking to address.

Comment: @pilchard not sure where you see the overlap, I am not using any out-of-flow property so nothing should overlap

Comment: Is there any way to do it without position sticky? The browser support doesn't seem very good (like 20% full support globally and then there's prefixes, etc.)

Comment: `overflow-y: auto;` is set on `.outer`

Comment: @pilchard and ?

Comment: and thus the internal scrollbar that appears inside the `.outer` div overlaps the circle, which comes back to the ops question on conditionally setting the `right` value.

Comment: @RyanPeschel sticky is supported in all the major browser. It will fail only in IE which is not a surprise (you can still wait for more answers, the only one I see is with the use of sticky)

Comment: I was just referring to the caniuse page, which has a lot of scary warnings. But yeah if no other answer comes along I'll try this one

Comment: @RyanPeschel you need to correctly read the https://caniuse.com/css-sticky ... warning are for some particular uses cases which aren't present here ... all the browser with green and brown color support sticky. The ones with brown have some particular issues (that you can read on hover) .. Only the red will fail (the IE browser)

Comment: Yeah, it's not as bad as it originally looks, but there is still quite a decent amount of red. Well, in any case I'll probably use this unless something else comes along.

Comment: @RyanPeschel there is only 2 red, IE and opera mini .. you should not consider all the cells, only the last highlighted row. Caniuse show all the versions so you know when the support started. Chrome 4 doesn't support it but who care? we are now at V85 (same for all the browsers)

Comment: Chrome only started supporting it in version 56 it seems.